# How do I toggle between textviews?

Tags: string, if-statement, textview, boolean, findviewbyid

What should I add so that I can toggle between textviews upon each click? It only works for one click. This is probably an easy fix, so thanks in advance!

```
    public void status(View view) {
        TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            if (textView2.getText() == "uhuh") {
                textView2.setText("u uh");
            } else {
                textView2.setText("u huh");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void status(View view) {
        TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        String check = textView2.getText().toString();
        if (check.equals("u huh")) {
            textView2.setText("u uh");
        }
        else{
            textView2.setText("u huh");
        }
    }
```